# pyspark linear regression model gives error this column name must be numeric type but was actually string type

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am making a multi-nominal regression model in pyspark and after running my linear regression model it gives me this error 
        "IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Column label must be  of type NumericType but was actually of type StringType."

Please help me here as I have spent so much time to resolve this but couldn't ale to solve.

```
    lr_data=   loan_data.select('int_rate','loan_amnt','term','grade','sub_grade','emp_length','verification_status','home_ownership','annual_inc','purpose','addr_state','open_acc') 
    lr_data.printSchema()

    root
    |-- int_rate: string (nullable = true)
    |-- loan_amnt: integer (nullable = true)
    |-- term: string (nullable = true)
    |-- grade: string (nullable = true)
    |-- sub_grade: string (nullable = true)
    |-- emp_length: string (nullable = true)
    |-- verification_status: string (nullable = true)
    |-- home_ownership: string (nullable = true)
    |-- annual_inc: double (nullable = true)
    |-- purpose: string (nullable = true)
    |-- addr_state: string (nullable = true)
    |-- open_acc: string (nullable = true)
```

here in the multinominol regression model my target variable should be int_rate(which is string type, probably that's why i am getting this error while running).

but initially i tried using only two values in the regression model which are int_rate,loan_amnt.

here is the code

```
    input_data=lr_data.rdd.map(lambda x:(x[0], DenseVector(x[1:2])))
    data3= spark.createDataFrame(input_data,["label","features",])
    data3.printSchema()

   root
   |-- label: string (nullable = true)
   |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```

IMP:NOTE I tried with taking other variables in DenseVector array but it was throwing me long error something like invalide literal for float(): 36 months

```
   usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.pyc in createDataFrame(self,    data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    580 
    581         if isinstance(data, RDD):
    582  rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
   583         else:
   584             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
    if schema is None or isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
    380             struct = self._inferSchema(rdd, samplingRatio)
    381             converter = _create_converter(struct)
    382             rdd = rdd.map(converter)

   /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.pyc in _inferSchema(self,   rdd, samplingRatio)
    349         :return: :class:`pyspark.sql.types.StructType`
    350         """
    351         first = rdd.first()
    352         if not first:
    353             raise ValueError("The first row in RDD is empty, "
```

Please tell me how to select more than 2 variable in this regression model as well. I guess i have to typecast every variable in my data set.

```
   #spilt into two partition 
   train_data, test_data = data3.randomSplit([.7,.3], seed = 1)
   lr = LinearRegression(labelCol="label", maxIter=100, regParam= 0.3, elasticNetParam = 0.8)
   linearModel = lr.fit(train_data)
```

Now when i am running this linearmodel() I am getting this below error.

```
    IllegalArgumentException Traceback (most recent call  last)
   <ipython-input-20-5f84d575334f> in <module>()
```

---->    1 linearModel = lr.fit(train_data)

```
     /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.pyc in fit(self,dataset,params) 
      62                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
      63             else:
      64                 return self._fit(dataset)
      65         else:
      66             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map  or a list/tuple of param maps, "

      /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.pyc in _fit(self, dataset)
      263 
      264     def _fit(self, dataset):
      265         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
      266         return self._create_model(java_model)
      267 

      /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.pyc in _fit_java(self, dataset)
        260         """
        261         self._transfer_params_to_java()
        262         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
        263 
        264     def _fit(self, dataset):

       /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
        1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
        1132         return_value = get_return_value(
        1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
```

1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

```
       /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
        77                 raise QueryExecutionException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
        78             if  s.startswith('java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '):
```

--->        79                 raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
            80             raise
            81     return deco

```
        IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Column label must be of type NumericType but was actually of type StringType.'
```

Please help me, I have tried every method of casting string value to numeric but doesn't make any difference. As my int_rate which is target variable is string types by deafult but it takes value of numeric.one more is I have to select the whole lr data set in my regression model. How can i do this. 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

cols = lr_data.columns
input_data = lr_data.rdd.map(lambda x:(x['int_rate'], Vectors.dense([x[col] for col in cols if col != 'int_rate'])))\
                        .toDF(["label","features",])\
                        .select([F.col('label').cast(FloatType()).alias('label'), 'features'])

train_data, test_data = input_data.randomSplit([.7,.3], seed = 1)

lr = LinearRegression(labelCol="label", maxIter=100, regParam= 0.3, elasticNetParam = 0.8)
linearModel = lr.fit(train_data)
```

This is provided your all columns are or can be converted to numeric types.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tried for int_rate this code
      from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
     loan_data = loan_data.withColumn("int_rate",   loan_data.int_rate.cast(IntegerType()))
     and it converted int_rate to numeric type but after running data3= spark.createDataFrame(input_data,["label","features"]) it gives me the error of "ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined by the first 100 rows, please try again with sampling" any suggestion please

Comment: ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined by the first 100 rows, please try again with sampling

after running 
data3= spark.createDataFrame(input_data,["label","features"])

Comment: Try setting samplingRatio in createDataFrame to a higher value (example: 0.4)

Comment: data3= spark.createDataFrame(input_data,  ["label","features"],"samplingRatio", "0.5")

data3.show(5, truncate = False)
-----+---------+
     |label|features |
     +-----+---------+
     |null |[5000.0] |
     |null |[2500.0] |


linearModel = lr.fit(train_data)

Now this giving me this error. all my values in int_rate has been NULL?

error:
       u'requirement failed: Column label must be of type NumericType     but was actually of type NullType.'

Comment: Were they null from starting?

Comment: Well you need to label encode the features. Only then they can be converted to numeric types. Can you show a sample of data?

Comment: I uploaded my data please help :)

Comment: uploaded the lr_data

Comment: Ye! you need to strip '%' from target, use VectorAssembler ,stringIndexer to transfrm categorical variables after which you can use above code.

Comment: would you give me some hint??
you mean all my string variables i have to convert first with string-indexer then onehotencoder and then vectorassembler?

and how can i use all my variables into multinomial regression model?

some code will be great help :)

Comment: you need to strip '%' from target

sorry i didn't understand this...strip